# Export to word with a filename doesn't seem to work

Tags: asp.net, filenames, export-to-word

I export a datatable to word, when I pass a file name it doesn't seem to get the file name in Open/Save dialog box.

Here is what I am doing

```
public static void Convertword(DataTable dt, HttpResponse Response,string filename)
{
    try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".doc");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.word";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView dg = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
        dg.DataSource = dt;
        dg.DataBind();
        dg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

When I pass filename `"report(" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
+ ")"` it doesn't take the value as **dd/MM/YYYY** instead it shows file name as **dd_MM_YYYY**

Comment: So the problem is de file save dialog says "dd_MM_yyyy" instead of "dd/MM/yyyy" or the problem is it says anything else (like mypage.aspx...)?

If you want to send an actual Word file you should use some library for writing Word files and write to the response outputstream (it is, send the bytes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few remarks about your code:

1. You are setting the content type header to a word document but you are actually sending HTML contents by rendering a GridView
2. `dd/MM/YYYY` is not a valid filename because of the `/` character.
3. You don't need a `try/catch` block if in the `catch` statement you are only doing `throw err`
4. Calling `Response.End` at the end is not necessary.
5. Always use `using` statement when dealing with disposable objects such as streams and readers/writers to ensure that the `Dispose` method is invoked in all cases.

Comment: In addition to point 3: `throw err;` is bad practice because it removes the call stack. Simply use `throw;` instead if you want to re-throw an exception.

Comment: I replaced my Response.End with HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Comment: And in addition to point 1: This actually works although it might seem wrong (Try renaming an .html file to .doc and it will be opened in Word).

Answer (score 2):

You should to use a filename like

```
String.Format("report{0:ddMMyyyy}.doc", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

A filename cannot have "/".

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely because `/` isn't a valid character for filenames. Your name must fulfill certain criteria, be sure not to use any of

> `* . " / \ [ ] : ; | = ,`

Answer (score 0):

If you have forward slashes in the filename, I would assume that this would break the URL to the file and hence the slashes are being replaced at some point?