# String concatenation doesn't seem to work in C#

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

I don't know what is wrong with the following string:

```
"Report(" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + "  to  " + System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") +  ")"
```

I can't get the concatenated string.  I am getting `Report(29-Dec-2009`. That's all and 
the rest gets left out from the string.

What is the reason?

Comment: Could you provide some details of the result that you are seeing? Are you getting an exception? Do you get a string result that you were not expecting?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint right after this code is executed. Check the value of the variable to which it is assigned. This will rule out any truncation that occurs later.

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and I suspect the answer will become clear. The single expression shown *isn't* the problem (although I'd argue that using `String.Format` would be cleaner).

Comment: Where are you seeing the "Report(29-Dec-2009" string? In the debugger? When printing the string to the console? When being displayed on the screen in a field that can only display 18 characters at a time?

Comment: I bet you only *see* the first half, but the variable *contains* all of the message. Must be something like to short label size, etc.

Comment: He's probably talking about his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973843/export-to-word-with-a-filename-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
string filename = 
    String.Format(
        "Report({0:dd-MMM-yyyy} to {1:dd-MMM-yyyy})",
         System.DateTime.Now, System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1));
```

**EDIT:** Since in your **download box** you got your filename broken in first whitespace, you could to try ONE of these:

```
filename = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename); // OR
filename = """" + filename + """";
```

Seems some browsers doesn't handles whitespaces very nicely: [Filenames with spaces are truncated upon download](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download). Please check it you can to download other filenames with whitespace in other sites.

Comment: i am passing this string filename to my report header and it doesnt seem to take my file name..

Comment: @Rubens I want file name to be Report(29-Dec-2009 to 29-Nov-2009) but my filename in Save/Open Dialog shows Report(29-Dec-2009..

Comment: @ruben why this file name doesnt show in my open/save dialog box as i am exporting repots for last one month

Comment: @rubens firefox seems to ignore file name from first white space

Comment: so you got a browser problem, not a C#; you can to replace all whitespaces from your filename with `_`, like `filename = filename.Replace(" ", "_");`

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign it to something:

```
string s = "Report(" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " to " + System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ")"
```

Update: I just saw your update to the question. How are you displaying the string? I'm guessing that you are displaying it in a GUI and the label is too short to display the complete text.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string newstring = 
  string.Format(
                "Report ({0} to {1})", 
                System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), 
                System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
               );
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you assigning the result to? It would be easier to read the code if you used string.Format

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the concatenated result to anything, so can't use it:

```
string myConcatenated = "Report(" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code...

```
string test = "Report(" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " to " +
                   System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ")";
```

I saw the following result.

```
Report(29-Dec-2009 to 29-Nov-2009)
```

It could be that the string is being truncated later on. Make sure that you set a breakpoint right after this code is run and check the value of the variable to which it is assigned (test in my case).

Answer (score 0):

If, as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973843/export-to-word-with-a-filename-doesnt-seem-to-work), you are using this value to create a file, it may be that it's the space before "to" that is causing the problem. Try to use:

```
"Report("
    + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
    + "To"
    + System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
    +  ")"
```

instead and see if that fixes it.

If that *does* fix it, you'll probably need to either figure out how to quote the entire file name so it's not treated as the three separate arguments, `"Report(29-Dec-2009"`, `"to"` and `"29-Nov-2009)"`. Or simply leave your reports names without spaces.

I'd choose the latter but then I'm fundamentally opposed to spaces in filenames - they make simple scripts so much harder to write :-)